# query search on an index with two different documents type

Tags: java, lucene

i've an index in which there are heterogeneous documents. These documents have only 1 common field (a personal id) for example:

DOC 
id: 7
content: this example content doc has a long text
type: content

DOC
id: 7
title: example doc
public: yes
type: metadata

i've chosen this solution because i want to manage the long text documents separately from the metadata documents.

If i perform a query like this

```
+(content: example title: example) +public: yes
```

lucene return correctly the document type "metadata" with id 7 but if i perform this other one:

```
+(content: long) +public: yes
```

lucene doesn't return me the document because the clause +public: yes (necessary for my application) corresponds to a field not in "content" type document.

My question: how can i ask  lucene to give back the "content" document that has the "public" field "yes" contained into the other document with the same id (with only a single query)?

Sorry for my english, thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work if you didn't make the 'public' field required. So:

```
+(content: long) public: yes
```

Or can you strip the 'public' field out of the query string before submitting it to Lucene?

Comment: The metadata "public" is necessary... i can't return a document type "content" which has the corresponding metadata "public" to false. Yes i can strip the public condition out of query, but, if i do that, lucene returns me "content" document with relative metadata both "true" and "false".

Comment: OK, I see. Sounds like you want to do a join query. I don't think you can do that with the default Lucene query parser, though. You could write something to handle your case specifically using the query API if it's not too complex. Alternatively, it looks like Solr supports join queries: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join, although I have not used them.

Comment: Unfortunately, now  I have unified the two documents, because this problem has made me a mad programmer!